# Expectation of a step function and its extension to bounded above functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that

$$E_{\mu}[e^{-\alpha T}f(X)]=\int_{\chi}f(x)M_{\mu}(dx)$$

where $f$ is a measurable step function on Borel space $\chi$, $M_{\mu}$ is a nonnegative measure on $\chi$, $T$ (nonnegative) and $X$ are random variables on $\chi$, and $\mu$ is an initial distribution on $\chi$. In a book that I read, it is said that if the above statement is true, then the same statement is also true for every bounded above measurable function $f$. Probably, it is very fundamental, but I could not see how it follows.

Thanks